# Apache rewrite path to paramater

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How would i convert:

`https://www.example.com/ja` to redirect to `https://www.example.com/?lng=ja`

I've tried the apache rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ja$ /?lng=ja&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

but I just get a 404 when accessing `https://www.example.com/ja`

I've also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^ja$ /?lng=ja
```

Which just loads the home page with /ja but doesn't seem to add on the url param

Comment: Are you placing the directive in .conf file or in .htaccess?

Comment: @DusanBajic placing in .htaccess as the conf is set to allow overrides from the .htaccess. It's definitely doing something hence the either 404 or different page loads when i try different things, it's just not doing what i desire.

Comment: If you want the rule to do the redirect, you need `[R]` flag at the end of the line

Comment: @DusanBajic omg it was that simple! That worked :) If you want to put it as an answer, I'll mark as accepted. Is there a way to rewrite but keep the url looking the same, like an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `RewriteRule ^ja$ /?lng=ja [R,L]`

By default, [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) maps a URL to a filesystem path, but it can also be used to redirect one URL to another URL.

Use of the [`[R]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) causes a HTTP redirect to be issued to the browser. If a fully-qualified URL is specified (that is, including `http://servername/`) then a redirect will be issued to that location. Otherwise, the current protocol, servername, and port number will be used to generate the URL sent with the redirect.

You will almost always want to use `[R]` in conjunction with `[L]` (that is, use `[R,L]`) because on its own, the `[R]` flag prepends http://thishost[:thisport] to the URI, but then passes this on to the next rule in the ruleset, which can often result in 'Invalid URI in request' warnings.